# Copy file from FTP to S3 bucket using boto3 and ftplib is failing with "500 Syntax error, command unrecognized"

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ftp, boto3, ftplib

I need to send data from an FTP server into an S3 bucket without saving the file to my local drive. On the internet, I found that we can use `io.BytesIO()` as buffer. But my code fails with:

> error_perm: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.

[image]

The script:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(ipaddr)
ftp.login(usr,pswd)
ftp.cwd(folder)
myfile = io.BytesIO()
buffer = ftp.retrbinary(filename, myfile.write)
myfile.seek(0)
s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, folder + "/" + filename).put(Body=buffer)
ftp.quit()
```

Aany one can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems with your code:

1. Your immediate problem is, that you are missing the FTP command (`RETR`) in the [`Connection.retrbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) call. That's why you get *"error_perm: 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized."*. It should be:

   ```
   ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, myfile.write)
   ```
2. Once you solve that, you will see that the contents won't make it to the S3, as you are passing FTP response (`buffer`), instead of the downloaded contents (`myfile`) to S3, as @dreamca4er commented. It should be:

   ```
   s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, folder + "/" + filename).put(Body=myfile)
   ```

Comment: yes, my silly mistake. thank you